# FilterPickList not removing default values from drop down in extjs 6

Tags: tags, extjs6, extjs6-classic

I have a component like

```
Ext.define('Abc.view.main.Indicator', {
    extend: 'Ext.form.field.Tag',
    xtype: 'indicator',
    fieldLabel: 'indicator',
    name: 'indicator',
     filterPickList: true,
    displayField: 'value',
     value:'N',
    valueField: 'key',
    store: {
        type: 'indicator'
    }
});


Ext.define('Abc.store.Indicator', {
    extend: 'Ext.data.Store',
    alias: 'store.indicator',
    fields: ['key', 'value'],
    proxy: {
        type: 'memory',
        reader: {
            type: 'array'
        }
    },
    data: [
        ["ALL", "ALL"],
        ["Y", "Y"],
        ["N", "N"]
    ]
});
```

If u see i have put N as default value. But N does not get removed from the dropdown list even though i have put filterPickList: true. Is there anything i need to write code for this?

Answer (score 0):

The Layout doesnt seem to refresh when the picker is expanded. Probablly a bug in Xjs6. A temporary workaround is to write a listeners durinf expand event

```
Ext.define('Abc.view.main.Indicator', {
extend: 'Ext.form.field.Tag',
xtype: 'indicator',
fieldLabel: 'indicator',
name: 'indicator',
 filterPickList: true,
displayField: 'value',
 value:'N',
valueField: 'key',
store: {
    type: 'indicator'
},
listeners:{
    expand:function(me){
        me.doLayout();//this will refresh the combo and picker
    }
}
});
```